# Render images in canvas on main form from within another class

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to render some Image objects in a canvas (**Layout**) on the main form of my application which is called **Main**. I am using C# and WPF to create the application but am unable to get the images to render from within another class but works without problems in the **Main** form partial class.

```
public static void renderStarscape(int density = 200)
    {
        Main main = new Main();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int x = 0; x < density; x++)
        {
            int starSize = random.Next(1, 10);
            int starOpacity = random.Next(10, 30);
            int starX = random.Next(0, 800);
            int starY = random.Next(0, 500);
            Image Star = new Image();
            Star.Name = (x < 10) ? "star_0" + x : "star_" + x;
            Star.Source = streamImage("star_background.png");
            Star.Height = starSize;
            Star.Width = starSize;
            Star.Opacity = (double)starOpacity / 100;
            main.Layout.Children.Add(Star);
            Canvas.SetLeft(Star, starX);
            Canvas.SetTop(Star, starY);
            Canvas.SetZIndex(Star, 0);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an all `new instance of Main` in the method which is not same as the one shown on UI.

Instead pass on the instance of the Canvas to the method and draw on that something like this -

```
public static void renderStarscape( Canvas layout, int density = 200)
{
    // Use layout and remove the Main object initialization from the method.
    layout.Children.Add(Star);
}
```

The reason its working in partial declaration of class is that you are using the same instance and not creating the new one for `Main()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, i only just started learning C# 2 days ago so i am bound to make some silly mistakes.

Comment: it should be ``public static void renderStarscape(Canvas layout, int density = 200)`` though as mandatory parameters must always be declared first.

Comment: Yeah right.. Updated the answer.. You are learning quickly.. :)

Comment: Thanks, i do often surprise myself with how quickly i pick up new skills.